# Why does my trait definition compile with the 2015 edition but not with the 2018 edition?

Tags: rust, rust-2018

I wrote this simple program:

```
trait Command<T> {                                                                                                      
    fn execute(&self, &mut T);                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                       

fn main() {                                                                                                             
    let x = 0;                                                                                                          
}
```

I compiled this with `rustc --edition=2018 main.rs` and get the error message:

```
error: expected one of `:` or `@`, found `)`
 --> main.rs:2:29
  |
2 |     fn execute(&self, &mut T);
  |                             ^ expected one of `:` or `@` here
```

Compiling via `rustc --edition=2015 main.rs` or `rustc main.rs` doesn't cause this error, although there are some warnings.

What's the problem with this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anonymous trait parameters have been removed in 2018 edition: [No more anonymous trait parameters](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/no-anon-params.html).

Add `_:` before `&mut T` if you want to ignore the parameter:

```rust
trait Command<T> {
    fn execute(&self, _: &mut T);
}
```

Compiling with `rustc main.rs` works, because it defaults to `--edition=2015`.

---

Indeed, if you put your `main.rs` in a new Cargo project, then remove `edition = "2018"` from `Cargo.toml`, and run

```
cargo fix --edition
```

then Cargo will add the missing `_:` automatically. See [Transitioning an existing project to a new edition](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/editions/transitioning-an-existing-project-to-a-new-edition.html).